d3.scaleOrdinal is not a function
I am trying to run a sunburst graph taken from this GitHub.

<head>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/d3"></script>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="//unpkg.com/sunburst-chart"></script>
  <!--<script src="../../dist/sunburst-chart.js"></script>-->

  <style>body { margin: 0 }</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>

  <script>
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePaired);

    fetch('flare.json').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      Sunburst()
        .data(data)
        .label('name')
        .size('size')
        .color((d, parent) => color(parent ? parent.data.name : null))
        .tooltipContent((d, node) => `Size: <i>${node.value}</i>`)
        (document.getElementById('chart'));
    });
  </script>
</body>

However, I am using version 3 of the d3 library because other components of my interface work with that version.
I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: d3.scaleOrdinal is not a function

Does anyone know how I can solve this?
I tried to use:
const color = d3.scale.ordinal(d3.schemePaired);

as suggested here, but d3 is not able to correctly set the colors for my sunburst, since it sets all the slices' colors to black.

Color scales were very different back in version 3.   See here for what was available.

d3.schemePaired is a predefined color scheme in D3.js that provides a set of 12 colors designed to be distinguishable even when viewed as a pair. This color scheme was introduced in D3.js version 4 and is commonly used for categorical data.
If you're using D3.js version 3 (d3.v3.js), d3.schemePaired won't be available because it was introduced in version 4. In D3.js version 3, you'd typically define your own color scale or use another predefined scheme if available.
    // Define a color scale using d3.scale.category10()
    var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

    // Example data categories
    var categories = ["Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5"];

